# simple string cipher in C (const char difficulties)

Tags: c, pointers, constants, encryption

hi all ive created a simple little cipher function that can take a pointer to a string and then change each byte to its corresponding ciphered character and if you run it back through the function it will turn the text back into plain text.

my problem though is that i would like to use this function with `const char *p = "...";` declared variables but that is simply not possible because these are loaded into memory at run time and are non writable.

here is my function.

```
char *Cipher(char *str)
{
    char *p = str;

    while(*p)
    {
        if(*p >= ' ' && *p <= 'O')
        {
            *p = ((*p + 48) % 127);
        }
        else if(*p >= 'P' && *p <= '~')
        {
            *p = ((*p - 48) % 127);
        }

        p++;
    }
    return str;
}
```

it simply takes a pointer to a string and then replaces all the characters and returns the pointer back to the string (so that i can use it inside other functions such as printf or anything that accepts `char*` as an argument).

now i know in order to work with these `const char*` pointers i am going to have to copy them into local memory to the function to modify them, but how can return a pointer to the newly encoded or decoded string so i can pass it to other functions. (the ultimate goal is to include it into a simple chat program and i would like to call it something like `send(sock, Cipher(PRE_HEADER), strlen(PRE_HEADER));`) also i assume that my way of doing this wont be thread safe, so just in case i ever decide to use this with a threaded application what changes would i have to make?

i am also accepting other alternative code for simple string substitution ciphers.

any help would be appreciated. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can duplicate the string in `Cipher` function using `strdup` and work on it, and return pointer of new string.

Something like:

```
char *Cipher(char *str)
{
    char *new_string = strdup(str);
    char *p = new_string;

    while(*p)
    {
        if(*p >= ' ' && *p <= 'O')
        {
            *p = ((*p + 48) % 127);
        }
        else if(*p >= 'P' && *p <= '~')
        {
            *p = ((*p - 48) % 127);
        }

        p++;
    }
    /* return new_string not p */
    return new_string;
}
```

Also, you will have to change caller code as below to use new string in `strlen` function. But if you really know length of string passed to `Cipher` will be *always* same a return string then you can still use `strlen(PRE_HEADER)`.

```
str = Cipher(PRE_HEADER);
send(sock, str, strlen(str));
```

Comment: If you rewrite your function like this, you might consider changing the signature to `char *Cipher(const char *str)` (note the `const`) to quiet any lingering compiler warnings.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to use

```
strncpy( str, All.c_str(), sizeof( str ) );
```

in some helper function or right before your call to

```
send(sock, Cipher(PRE_HEADER), strlen(PRE_HEADER));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try declaring your variables as `char` arrays rather than `char` pointers, a la:

```
char p[] = "...";
```

You will have nearly the same effect as before — you can pass `p` into a function, and it will decay nicely to a pointer — but instead of being stored in read-only memory, `p` will be stored where it is declared (either on the stack inside a function, or if you make it a static, in your program's data segment).